# How to get unique pairs from two columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I am stuck on exercise 68 from http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref.

The database consists of these four tables:

1. Company(ID_comp, name)
2. Trip(trip_no, id_comp, plane, town_from, town_to, time_out, time_in)
3. Passenger(ID_psg, name)
4. Pass_in_trip(trip_no, date, ID_psg, place)

The objective of the exercise is: 
Find out the number of routes with the greatest number of flights (trips).
Notes.

1. A - B and B - A are to be considered the SAME route.
2. Use the Trip table only.

I can get the correct answer for "Find out the number of routes with the greatest number of flights (trips)," but not when considering Notes 1: A - B and B - A are to be considered the SAME route.

I don't how to get unique pairs:
If we have the output:

```
| town_from | town_to   | count |
| --------- | --------- | ----- |
| London    | Singapore | 4     |
| Singapore | London    | 4     |
```

How do I Select so that it only gives me

```
| town_from | town_to   | count |
| --------- | --------- | ----- |
| London    | Singapore | 4     |
```

I was able to complete the problem with the following query:

WITH x AS(
SELECT con, sum(c) as s FROM(
SELECT town_from, town_to, 'con' = CASE WHEN lower(town_from)

SELECT count(*) FROM x
WHERE s = (SELECT max(s) FROM x)

Comment: What database are you using?  MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag correctly.

Comment: Please post attempted query that yields your current output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look at the `Trip` table in a way that represents from->to the same way as it does to->from. A typical way to do this is make sure it is always sorted `town_from <(=) town_to`.

Generically speaking, the following query will project `Trip` in such a way. The case clause switches from and to around to keep them always sorted:

```
select trip_no, id_comp, plane, 
    case when town_from < town_to then town_from else town_to end as town_from, 
    case when town_from < town_to then town_to else town_from end as town_to, 
    time_out, time_in
from Trip
```

You can then select from this projection in your query:

```
select ...
from (
    select trip_no, id_comp, plane, 
        case when town_from < town_to then town_from else town_to end as town_from, 
        case when town_from < town_to then town_to else town_from end as town_to, 
        time_out, time_in
    from Trip
) as x
```

---

To solve this particular problem we can apply the same logic, but remove the unnecessary columns (the optimizer should do this anyway but it looks cleaner to the human eye):

```
select town_from, town_to, count(*)
from (
    select 
        case when town_from < town_to then town_from else town_to end as town_from, 
        case when town_from < town_to then town_to else town_from end as town_to 
    from Trip
) as x
group by town_from, town_to
```

Note: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in your expected output the total count of London<->Singapore should be *8*, not *4*. You have 4 trips in one direction and 4 in the other, for a total of 8.

Then we can use the same query to find the greatest number of flights, then find the routes with that number, then count. I suspect you have this part down but this is left as an exercise.

Comment: in addendum, basically the logic is switching location field according to alphabetical order then making it the base table.

Comment: @lc. this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the explanation. I figured out a way to answer the problem by concatenating town_from and town_to using a case statement, but Your example is much cleaner, and what I was looking for. Thanks again. I upvoted your answer, but my rep is too low :D.

Answer (score 0):

````
select a.town_from, a.town_to, count(a.plane) ta from (
select plane, 
(case when town_from < town_to then town_from else town_to end) as town_from, 
(case when town_from < town_to then town_to else town_from end) as town_to 
from trip) as a
group by a.town_from, a.town_to
having count(a.plane) >= all (select count(plane) from trip group by plane, town_from, town_to)) s```
````